# Mediaplayer.prepare() crash with IllegalStateException, only for Xiaomi Note 3 & Xiaomi Mi4

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, illegalstateexception

For my alarm app, this error is coming only for **Xiaomi Note 3** & **Xiaomi Mi4** devices &  working fine for all other devices including my personsal Xiaomi Redmi 3S.

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 

java.lang.IllegalStateException :
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException:
android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare (MediaPlayer.java)
android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare (MediaPlayer.java:1408)
android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6912)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1126)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2877)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2985)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14 (ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1635)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6692)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1468)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you provide `data-source` before `MediaPlayer.prepare()`

Since `MediaPlayer.prepare()` blocks the main thread, which results in an exception. To prevent this, try `MediaPlayer.prepareAsync()` instead of `MediaPlayer.prepare()`. For this apporach read `onPreparedListener()` and `onErrorListener()` 
If this didn't help, please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35079310/mediaplayer-prepare-showing-illegal-state-exception), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061436/illegalstateexception-for-mediaplayer-prepareasync) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445663/mediaplayer-prepare-is-throwing-an-illegalstateexception-when-playing-m4a-file)

Comment: Any reason why MediaPlayer.prepare() is failing only for Xiaomi & some Samsung Galaxy devices, but not for others ? Also I am only using device media & not doing online buffering.

Comment: In my app, if the user doesn't set a ringtone/alarm/music-file of his choice in settings, then the default ringtone rings.

The problem is only coming in the scenarios where the default ringrone rings & user hasn't set a ringtone/alarm/music-file in app settings .

Comment: Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);

This code is working fine on all other devices.

Comment: This fix should work.
            Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);

                if (uri == null) {
                    uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);

                    if (uri == null) {
                        // alert backup is null, using 2nd backup
                        uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                    }

                }
Looks like TYPE_RINGTONE is returning null only for these devices.

Comment: import a default tune in your assets and in case of `uri = null` set `uri` to that tune.

Comment: That's a nice solution. From what I have read, default notification should not return null for any device. If still crashes happen for any device, then I would go ahead with  your suggestion.

Comment: yeah, it's a good hack. Also remember to accept this answer :)